# How do I make my ASP.Net website viewable in my private home network using IIS 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, iis-6

I want to know how I can make website available in my private home network? I know I am supposed to make my IP address static but I still do not know the complete steps to accomplish what I want to do. Is this even possible? If it is can someone please explain to me what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy but you need to read up on some security before making anything live.

Static IP addresses cost more money than dynamic ones so I suggest signing up to http://www.no-ip.com/. It's requires installing a program which updates a domain which your ip address everytime it changes.

You will also need to use port forwarding on your router so it knows to send all http requests to your PC. HTTP data to passed normally through port 80 or 8080.

Hope this helps.

Comment: HTTP is typically transmitted on port 80

Comment: I see you updated to ..80 or 8080 - but that is wrong. When a user opens their browser and types in a domain name, that request is received by the server on port 80 - period. Port 8080 has to do with TCP - so you can manually send requests, and if the server is listening, it may respond, but this is not the norm.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of ISP's won't allow you to receive requests on port 80. However, you can test this by trying...

-Install IIS - when you go to http://localhost, you should see an IIS start page.

-If you have a router/switch, you'll need to access the admin interface on it. This is usually default 192.168.1.1, but varies by manufacturer. You'll also need to get the local IP address of your IIS server. Go to run, hit CMD, and type IPCONFIG.

-Inside the admin interface, you'll have port forwarding. Forward port 80 to the IP address of your IIS server. Save.
-Now, get your actual IP address by going to a site like whatsmyip.com.

That should do it. Ask a friend or a family member to browse to your IP address. If they see your site, your ISP allows you to host. If they don't see it, your ISP has it blocked..

Having said that, you should check out serverfault.com - this question is more suited for that site.

Comment: +1 for pointing out most home ISP's won't allow incoming traffic on 80

Comment: @Chad Ruppert - +1 to you for being from Tampa, FL

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1y1404zt(v=VS.90).aspx